# Close file in program as gedit in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, terminal, sleep, c++-chrono

I was wondering how to close a program (e.g. gedit) that I opened with the terminal, 10 seconds after opening it. My approach is described bellow:

```
system("gedit ./fileName");

this_thread::sleep::chrono::seconds(10);

system("^C");
```

My problem is that, once I open gedit, the program doesn't seem to execute the next lines of code, after I close gedit manually.

I also had the idea of using another thread to close the process, but my execution didn't work.

Is there a way of closing gedit after opening it?
Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way might be to use a different method in which you (probably) fork a process as that'll get the PID of program you launched, which can be used to close / kill your program after some period.

Comment: Isn't there a way to open the file in a different manner with a certain program put the CPU to sleep for ten seconds and then close it? Or do I always have to locate the process and kill it with the PID?

Comment: Each time you call system() you open an independent shell